# Why deleted indexes appear when I restart the elasticsearch?

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I have some test indexes in the program,and I deleted them when I finish it.But when I restart the elasticsearch,They appear unexpectedly!

Comment: I have the cluster,and I deleted the index in one node,like this:curl -XDELETE http://localhost:9200/abc_test ,,,,but when I check the other node's file,I still  can see the abc_test.I use the elasticsearch 1.4.4 ,java version "1.7.0_04"

Comment: I think the replicas don't be deleted.

Comment: Can you update your question with the output of `curl 'localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'` ?

Comment: I have know the reason .Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

When you delete an index from elasticsearch, the index metadata is deleted from the cluster state and all index files are deleted on all node **currently connected** to the cluster. If a node that wasn't connected to the cluster when index is deleted later reconnects with the cluster, it may reintroduce the index back into the cluster. When this happens you should see the INFO message in the log files saying `[abc_test] dangling index, exists on local file system, but not in cluster metadata, auto import to cluster state`.

Comment: Got it. Thank you very much .

Comment: @LuoluoFlly please also see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work